# Extracting actual pixel number from `ginput()`

Tags: matlab, image-processing, affinetransform, ginput

I am using the following code on a given image:

```
imshow(image);
[out1,out2]=ginput(1);
```

I am getting a non-integer relative number.

- How do I extract the exact pixel numbers in `(row,column)` from the output of `ginput()`.
- I want to, later on, generate an affine transformation matrix (using `estimateGeometricTransform()`) to move points in one image to a second image. should I use the pixel number or the regular output of `ginput()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ginput` gives you relative positions, so

```
round(ginput(1))
```

should get you to the centre of the pixel, which is what you'll probably want, as it's difficult to select matching features on a level finer than pixels. If you can select features on a level finer than pixels, you should of course use that, and do that for both images.